# ASP.NET MVC installation on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, web-server, asp.net-mvc

When I install [ASP.NET MVC 3 RTM](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=D2928BC1-F48C-4E95-A064-2A455A22C8F6) on Windows Server 2008 R2 (Web server edition) will I also be able to run MVC 2 and MVC 1 web applications without installing them or do I need to install all of them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to install all 3 separately. If you want to avoid installing them altogether, you could bin deploy your applications. It's easy.

For mvc 3 with razor: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

For mvc 1 and 2:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx